# Warnings to determine unsafe casts clang

Tags: c++, casting, clang, long-integer

I am working on porting a legacy application to 64-bit on Linux. There are lots of places where long and int are used interchangeably and the source code being reasonably large makes it difficult to catch all of them by testing. I am planning to plugin use to statically analyze the code and fix unsafe code. One such pattern is

```
void foo(unsigned long *x){
    *x = *x + 1; //x is pointing to a 32-bit space
    return;
}

int main(){
    unsigned int x = ;
    foo(reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&x)); 
}
```

We use gcc-4.2.1 to build our application. And it doesn't warn me about these types of casts even with -Wall and -Wextra enabled.

I tried running clang with -Weverything but with no success. Is there a flag in clang to warn me about these type of risky explicit casts? If not, how do I go about adding one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that clang directly warns about the situation you are looking for. However, it is reasonably simple to create a plug-in detecting all uses of C-style casts and/or `reinterpret_cast<>()`s. There is an example of how to create a plug-in in the `tools/clang/examples/PrintFunctionNames` directory if you have a source tree. If you are located in the London area you might be interested in [my presentation](http://accu.org/index.php/accu_branches/accu_london) next Monday.

Comment: Thanks Dietmar! I wish I could attend but I don't stay close by. I ll have a look at the example and try to add a rule.

Comment: I did something like this gcc -Dreinterpret_cast=static_cast myfile.cpp and this started throwing out the errors I needed. I am pretty sure this will work for clang too. I will go ahead and add a rule for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Well the easiest way which comes in mind is simply find/replace all `reinterpret_cast` with `static_cast` and compile -  GCC will give you a bunch of errors about invalid `static_cast`

Comment: Thanks! That seems doable. I ll try that.

Comment: I did something like this gcc -Dreinterpret_cast=static_cast myfile.cpp and this started throwing out the errors I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You're casting explicitly by using `reinterpret_cast`, so the compiler assumes you know what you're doing. Otherwise you would get warning on every cast you do anywhere you do it.